# Erro no Deserialize C#

Tags: c#, json

Ao pegar as informações do meu Json e tento desserializar, o mesmo da erro ou exibe 0, já tentei N métodos, será que alguém me da uma luz? agradeço desde de já, segue o código.

//exemplo

```
{
"pulse": {
"url": "https://amdm.monday.com/projects/360886706",
"id": 360886706,
"name": "PO0008 -> Suporte Embraer",
"updates_count": 0,
"board_id": 251379198,
"created_at": "2019-10-28T20:04:36Z",
"updated_at": "2019-10-29T22:23:30Z"
},
"board_meta": {
"position": 65408,
"group_id": "new_group32"
},
"column_values": [
{
"cid": "name",
"title": "Name",
"name": "PO0008 -> Suporte Embraer"
},
{
"cid": "person90",
"title": "Pessoa",
"value": null
},
{
"cid": "date741",
"title": "Data",
"value": null
},
{
"cid": "status8",
"title": "Desenho",
"value": null
},
{
"cid": "person9",
"title": "Pessoa",
"value": null
},
{
"cid": "text7",
"title": "Nun SC/PC",
"value": null
},
{
"cid": "date03",
"title": "Data",
"value": null
},
{
"cid": "status14",
"title": "Compra Material",
"value": null
},
{
"cid": "people7",
"title": "People",
"value": null
},
{
"cid": "text73",
"title": "Qtd",
"value": null
},
{
"cid": "file",
"title": "File",
"value": null
},
{
"cid": "date8",
"title": "Data",
"value": null
},
{
"cid": "status5",
"title": "Produção",
"value": null
},
{
"cid": "n_meros",
"title": "HU-Naldo",
"value": null
},
{
"cid": "numbers0",
"title": "HU-Adão",
"value": null
},
{
"cid": "item_id",
"title": "Item ID",
"value": null
}
]
}
]
```

//-----------------------
//class

```
namespace AT_monday
{


    public class RootObject
    {
        [JsonProperty("pulse")]
        public Pulse[] pulse { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("board_meta")]
        public BoardMeta[] board_meta { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("column_values")]
        public List<ColumnValue>[] column_values { get; set; }
    }

    public class Pulse
    {
        [JsonProperty("url")]
        public string url { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public string id { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string name { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("updates_count")]
        public int updates_count { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("board_id")]
        public int board_id { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("created_at")]
        public DateTime created_at { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("updated_at")]
        public DateTime updated_at { get; set; }
    }

    public class BoardMeta
    {
        [JsonProperty("position")]
        public string position { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("group_id")]
        public string group_id { get; set; }
    }

    public class ColumnValue
    {
        [JsonProperty("cid")]
        public string cid { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("title")]
        public string title { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string name { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("value")]
        public object value { get; set; }

    }
}
```

//-------------

//codigo

```
var requisicaoWeb = WebRequest.CreateHttp(@"Url");
requisicaoWeb.Method = "GET";
requisicaoWeb.UserAgent = "RequisicaoWebDemo";
var resposta = requisicaoWeb.GetResponse();
var streamDados = resposta.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(streamDados);
string objResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();

var pedidosApi = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(objResponse);
txt1.Text = Convert.ToString(pedidosApi);
```

Comment: Bom dia, seu JSon tem um erro, existem vários formatadores online que te ajudam a formatar o seu Json facilitando você encontrar possíveis erros no código. Pode não ser somente isso, mas vale apenas você arrumar. Usei: https://jsonformatter.org Moacir.

Comment: O erro a que o @Moacir se refere é um colchete ("]") a mais no fim do JSON.